# Oracle 12c backup question with FRA

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

If I wanted to backup to the FRA and another location, how would I configure the channels? Also, would I need to set parallelism?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Duplexing Backup Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/bradv/backing-up-database-advanced.html#GUID-4CFE9BA0-E298-42B8-9FB6-D36751C09D54)

> ... It is not possible to duplex backup sets to the fast recovery
>   area.

A similar effect could be achieved by setting the format to the location of FRA, but it will not be the same, as these files will not be accounted in the space usage of FRA.

```
configure device type disk parallelism 2;
configure channel device type disk format   '/fra/%U',   '/oracle_backup/%U';
configure datafile backup copies for device type disk to 2;
configure archivelog backup copies for device type disk to 2;
configure default device type to disk;

backup database plus archivelog;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question wasn't that good. If I want to backup a database and archive logs to disk, to the FRA and another folder how would I do that? I am wondering because you cant set a format string if you are backing up to the FRA.

Comment: @dconner2006 OK, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to duplex the backup to multiple locations, why not backup the database to the FRA, then, in the same job, follow that with BACKKUP RECOVERY AREA